# Setting a UIImage as Background - NOT Tiled

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-graphics, uicolor

I have a Background Image Picker that lets the user select from stock images of from their Album.  To set the Image I have the Following code:

```
-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)newImage {    
    [backgroundImage release];
    backgroundImage = newImage;
    [backgroundImage retain];
    [editorContentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage]];
}
```

Though the Images are always tiled starting form the Top Right.  This works great for my 32x32 patterns, though if a User wants to use a 1024x768 Image on a 2048x2048 canvas and does not want it to tile, how can I prevent the tile?

My Only thought was to convert the Smaller Image to one that is the size of the Canvas, then set it to that.

Any Other Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always subclass UIView and use CoreGraphics to draw the image in -drawRect:

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with the Followinfg in drawRect: `
    if (tileBackgroundImage) {
        CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
        [backgroundImage drawAsPatternInRect:bounds];
    } else {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [backgroundImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    }
`

Answer (score 2):

Set the background transparent and create a separate `UIImageView`, which you can then place underneath.